# pygame - rects collision detection issue

Tags: python, pygame

I'm learning pygame and I have an issue with detection of rect's collisions. I'm using **colliderect()** function now but it works only when rects overlap, and the question is "How to detect even edges collisions?". General comments about the whole are welcome. First post btw.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame


#####SETTINGS#####
HEIGHT = 1080
WIDTH = 1920
BLOCK_SIZE = 60
##################


class Level():
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.blocks = []
        self.map = self.load_from_file()

    def load_from_file(self):
        map = []
        file = open(self.file + '.txt', 'r')
        data = file.read()
        file.close()
        data = data.split('\n')
        for x in data:
            map.append(list(x))
        return map
     
    def render(self, screen):
        self.blocks = []
        y = 0
        for row in self.map:
            x = 0
            for block in row:
                if block != '0':
                    self.blocks.append(pygame.Rect(x * BLOCK_SIZE, y * BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))
                    if block == '1':
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (56,24,0), (x * BLOCK_SIZE, y * BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))
                    elif block == '2':
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (18,115,81), (x * BLOCK_SIZE, y * BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))
                x += 1
            y += 1


class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE)
        self.go_left = False
        self.go_right = False
        self.go_up = False
        self.go_down = False
        self.collisions = {'left' : False, 'right' : False, 'top' : False, 'bottom' : False}

    def move(self):
        self.collisions = test_collisions(self.rect, level.blocks) 
        if self.go_left and not self.collisions['left']:
            self.x -= 10
            self.go_left = False
        if self.go_right and not self.collisions['right']:
            self.x += 10
            self.go_right = False
        if self.go_up and not self.collisions['top']:
            self.y -= 10
            self.go_up = False
        if self.go_down and not self.collisions['bottom']:
            self.y += 10
            self.go_down = False
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE)

    def render(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect)


def render(screen, player, level):
    screen.fill((49, 113, 181))
    level.render(screen)
    player.render(screen)
    pygame.display.update()


def handle_events(player):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.go_left = True
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.go_right = True
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player.go_up = True
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player.go_down = True


def test_collisions(object, rects):
    collisions = {'left' : False, 'right' : False, 'top' : False, 'bottom' : False}
    for rect in rects:
        if object.colliderect(rect):
            if object.x <= rect.x:
                collisions['right'] = True
            if object.x >= rect.x:
                collisions['left'] = True
            if object.y >= rect.y:
                collisions['top'] = True
            if object.y <= rect.y:
                collisions['bottom'] = True
    return(collisions)

    
def main_loop():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        handle_events(player)
        player.move()
        render(screen, player, level)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run = True
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    level = Level('assets/level_one')
    player = Player(0,0,(255,255,0))
    main_loop()
```

And here is **level_one.txt** file content:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000002222222222200000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00022222222200000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
22222222222222222222222222222222
11111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `enlarge the rectangles for the collision detection with [`pygame.Rect.inflate`]([builtins.TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935450/builtins-typeerror-argument-1-must-be-pygame-surface-not-function)). e.g.:

```py
if object.colliderect(rect.inflate(1, 1)):
    # [...]
```